# Converting Columns into rows with their respective data in sql server

Tags: sql-server, rows

I have a scenario where I need to convert columns of table to rows 
eg - 
table - stocks:

```
ScripName       ScripCode       Price   
-----------------------------------------
20 MICRONS      533022      39
```

I need to represent the table in the following format, but I just need this kind of representation for single row

```
ColName       ColValue
-----------------------------
ScripName      20 MICRONS
ScripCode      533022    
Price          39
```

so that I can directly bind the data to the datalist control.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
declare @T table (ScripName varchar(50), ScripCode varchar(50), Price int)
insert into @T values ('20 MICRONS', '533022', 39)

select 
  'ScripName' as ColName,
  ScripName as ColValue
from @T
union all
select 
  'ScripCode' as ColName,
  ScripCode as ColValue
from @T
union all
select 
  'Price' as ColName,
  cast(Price as varchar(50)) as ColValue
from @T
```

Answer (score 14):

Sound like you want to [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx)

Sample from books online:

```
--Create the table and insert values as portrayed in the previous example.
CREATE TABLE pvt (VendorID int, Emp1 int, Emp2 int,
    Emp3 int, Emp4 int, Emp5 int);
GO
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (1,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (2,4,1,5,5,5);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (3,4,3,5,4,4);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (4,4,2,5,5,4);
INSERT INTO pvt VALUES (5,5,1,5,5,5);
GO
--Unpivot the table.
SELECT VendorID, Employee, Orders
FROM 
   (SELECT VendorID, Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5
   FROM pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Employee IN 
      (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5)
)AS unpvt;
GO
```

Returns:

```
VendorID   Employee   Orders
---------- ---------- ------
1          Emp1       4
1          Emp2       3
1          Emp3       5
1          Emp4       4
1          Emp5       4
2          Emp1       4
2          Emp2       1
2          Emp3       5
2          Emp4       5
2          Emp5       5
```

see also: [Unpivot SQL thingie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268764/unpivot-sql-thingie) and the [unpivot tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unpivot)

Answer (score 3):

```
select 'ScriptName', scriptName from table
union all
select 'ScriptCode', scriptCode from table
union all
select 'Price', price from table
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative:

Using CROSS APPLY and VALUES performs this operation quite simply and efficiently with just a single pass of the table (unlike union queries that do one pass for every column)

```
SELECT
    ca.ColName, ca.ColValue
FROM YOurTable
CROSS APPLY (
      Values
         ('ScripName' , ScripName),
         ('ScripCode' , ScripCode),
         ('Price'     , cast(Price as varchar(50)) )
  ) as CA (ColName, ColValue)
```

Personally I find this syntax easier than using unpivot.

NB: You must take care that all source columns are converted into compatible types for the single value column

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
  (RowNo INT,ScripName  VARCHAR(10),ScripCode  VARCHAR(10)
  ,Price  VARCHAR(10))      
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
  (1,'20 MICRONS ','533022','39')
SELECT ColumnName,ColumnValue from @Table
 Unpivot(ColumnValue For ColumnName IN (ScripName,ScripCode,Price)) AS H
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the query this way

```
SELECT
    ca.ID, ca.[Name]
FROM [Emp2]
CROSS APPLY (
      Values
         ('ID' , cast(ID as varchar)),
         ('[Name]' , Name)

  ) as CA (ID, Name)
```

### output look like

```
  ID     Name
------ --------------------------------------------------
ID     1
[Name] Joy
ID     2
[Name] jean
ID     4
[Name] paul
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #ORIGINAL
(
    COUNTRY VARCHAR(50),
    MALE_CRICKETER VARCHAR(50),
    FEMALE_CRICKETER VARCHAR(50),
    MALE_STAR VARCHAR(50),
    FEMALE_STAR VARCHAR(50),
)

select * from #ORIGINAL 
SELECT COUNTRY, ca.GENDER, ca.STAR, ca.CRICKETR
FROM #ORIGINAL
CROSS APPLY (
      Values
         ('M', MALE_CRICKETER, MALE_STAR),
         ('F', FEMALE_CRICKETER, FEMALE_STAR)

  ) as CA (GENDER, CRICKETR, STAR)
```