# mysql - query to convert columns into rows

Tags: mysql, pie-chart

my query:

```
 SELECT ID, assiduos_a1, assiduos_a2, max(date)
   FROM cli_agendados_assiduos
  WHERE ID = 10357410;
```

which returns:

```
id          assiduos_a1 assiduos_a2 max(date)
10357410    337         508         08/01/2015 14:54:48
```

but I need the result in rows, like this:

```
Label       Value   id          max(date)
assiduos_a1 337     10357410    08/01/2015 14:54
assiduos_a2 508     10357410    08/01/2015 14:54
```

only in this format my graph (pie chart google) works correctly!

Comment: can you show the inpu data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql query to dynamically convert rows to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834290/mysql-query-to-dynamically-convert-rows-to-columns)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Columns into rows with their respective data in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337380/converting-columns-into-rows-with-their-respective-data-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
SELECT 'assiduos_a1', assiduos_a1 as value, id, max(date)
FROM cli_agendados_assiduos
WHERE ID = 10357410
UNION ALL
SELECT 'assiduos_a2', assiduos_a2 as value, id, max(date)
FROM cli_agendados_assiduos
WHERE ID = 10357410;
```