# SQL convert from 3 to 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I am trying to convert 3 columns into 2. Is there a way I can do this with the example below or a different way?

For example.

```
Year   Temp   Temp1
2015    5       6
```

Into:

```
Year   Value
Base     5
2015     6
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? E.g., there's a `PIVOT` operator for this, but it exists in MSSQL only.

Comment: SQL Server is the one I am using

Comment: Why does 6 gets 2015 as year, and 5 gets base?

Comment: @sagi Anything for temp1 gets assigned to 2015 and anything for temp gets assigned to baseline

Comment: @DeVonte This is an unpivot not a pivot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CROSS APPLY` and row constructor:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM t
CROSS APPLY(VALUES('Base', Temp),(CAST(Year AS NVARCHAR(100)), Temp1)
           ) AS s(year,value);
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/CAIMA64466)**</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

This is called unpivot, pivot is the exact opposite(make 2 columns into more) .

You can do this with a simple `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'Base',s.temp FROM YourTable s
UNION ALL
SELECT t.year,t.temp1 FROM YourTable t
```

This relays on what you wrote on the comments, if year is constant , you can replace it with '2015'

Comment: if you're using aliases in the query, you need to declare them

Comment: @RichBenner Hah didn't notice I didn't actually alias the tables. Thanks.

Comment: If `Year` is number you will get conversion error. Second first column is not named

Comment: I assumed by his example that he contains the year as a string. I guess it was since he said it worked. @lad2025

Answer (score 2):

There is more than one answer to your question. Using `UNION ALL` seems to be the most simple solution.

I suggest reading this thread [Converting Columns into rows with their respective data in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337380/converting-columns-into-rows-with-their-respective-data-in-sql-server), as it provides a lot more details, and you can try and test how different solutions will work for you.