# How to convert row values of database to column values while exporting data to excel sheet?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

```
user_id    meta_key  meta_value
1          name      abc
1          email     abc@gmail.com
1          phone     123
1          age       22
2          name      pqr
2          phone     456
3          name      xyz
3          email     xyz@gmail.com
3          phone     789
4          name      zzz
```

I have wordpress database saving user values as above but wile exporting this information to excel file, i want to format data as below.

```
user_id name    email           phone   age
1       abc     abc@gmail.com   123     22
2       pqr                     456 
3       xyz     xyz@gmail.com   789 
4       zzz
```

How it can be achieved?

Comment: you need to show us what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337380/converting-columns-into-rows-with-their-respective-data-in-sql-server) one

Comment: SELECT user_id , 

CASE WHEN (meta_key='nickname') THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END AS Name, 
CASE WHEN (meta_key='_cand_dob') THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END AS Date_Of_Birth, 
CASE WHEN (meta_key='_cand_gender') THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END AS Gender
FROM wp_usermeta
GROUP BY user_id


But its, returning null values for all columns except Name column.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`. You can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017).

You could write a simple `SELECT...CASE` statement, but generally this way is better and more readable. I would suggest you try writing the code yourself, but if there is something you do not understand, hit me up in the comments.

Comment: Hello, I have followed SELECT.. CASE condition. rows and columns are coming in expected result set but with null values though there are values in database.

Comment: @gangav Have you tried the `PIVOT` statement? It is far easier and more readable, which makes it easier debug-able if there are issues like this `NULL` one.

Comment: Yes. I tried that as well but that is saying syntax error.  

SELECT user_id, nickname, _cand_dob, _cand_gender FROM   
        (SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta ) AS Tab1 , 
PIVOT (SUM (meta_value) FOR meta_key IN (nickname,_cand_dob,_cand_gender ) )AS Tab2  
ORDER BY Tab2.user_id

Comment: @gangav I cannot write you the query right now, but on the first look, there is an extra comma after Tab1. `PIVOT` is not in the `SELECT` clause, but a difference clause altogether. Try to run the query without the extra comma between Tab1 and `PIVOT` and give me the result