# How to bring table values into temp table

Tags: sql-server, pivot, temp-tables

I have a sql query where SQL Server outputs  data to looks like this

| ScheduledAppts | KeptAppts | UnkeptAppts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 30 | 20 | 10 |

And  I want to alter this output into a sql server #temp table so it looks like this:

| Category | Count |
| --- | --- |
| ScheduledAppts | 30 |
| KeptAppts | 20 |
| UnkeptAppts | 10 |

Been trying to use Pivot but I think I'm doing it wrong.

Code:

```
SELECT

         COUNT(x.Scheduled) AS ScheduledAppts,

         COUNT(x.KeptEncounters) AS KeptAppts,

         COUNT(x.UnkeptEncounters) AS UnkeptAppts

   FROM (

         SELECT DISTINCT

                  COUNT(frz.TotalAppt) AS Scheduled,

                  CASE

                       WHEN frz.PDEncounters > 0 THEN

                       COUNT(frz.PDEncounters)

                  END AS KeptEncounters,

                  CASE

                       WHEN frz.PDEncounters = 0 THEN

                       COUNT(frz.PDEncounters)

                  END AS UnkeptEncounters,


           FROM [CDW].[dbo].[Fact_FREEZEPOLICE] frz

   ) x
```

Comment: On the specific point of temp tables.. Also take a look at CTE's. (Common Table Expressions) - using the `with` clause will often will scratch that itch! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to **UNPIVOT** here -

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ScheduledAppts INT, KeptAppts INT, UnkeptAppts INT)

INSERT INTO @T (ScheduledAppts, KeptAppts, UnkeptAppts)
SELECT 30, 20, 10

SELECT [Category]
    ,[Count]
FROM (
    SELECT ScheduledAppts
        ,KeptAppts
        ,UnkeptAppts
    FROM @T
    ) P
UNPIVOT([Count] FOR [Category] IN (
            ScheduledAppts
            ,KeptAppts
            ,UnkeptAppts
            )) AS UnPvt
```

Output:

| Category | Count |
| --- | --- |
| ScheduledAppts | 30 |
| KeptAppts | 20 |
| UnkeptAppts | 10 |

Reference: [Converting Columns into rows with their respective data in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337380/converting-columns-into-rows-with-their-respective-data-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross apply`:

```
select v.*
from output o cross apply
     (values ('ScheduledAppts', ScheduledAppts),
             ('KeptAppts', KeptAppts),
             ('UnkeptAppts', UnkeptAppts)
     ) v(category, count);
```

Note:  You might find it simpler to change the original query, if the original "table" is really a query result.