# How to convert columns into Rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table data where the data will be shown *like this :*

```
DatePeriod  Good    Fair    Poor    NotCategorised  NotTested   GoodPercentage  FairPercentage  PoorPercentage  NotCategorisedPercentage    NotTestedPercentage
Feb-13  4   0   0   0   60  6.25    0   0   0   93.75
```

And for this one I have written query using **UNPIVOT**.

```
Select DatePeriod,Legend FROM 
(
select DatePeriod,Good,Fair,Poor,NotCategorised,NotTested,GoodPercentage,
FairPercentage,poorPercentage,NotCategorisedPercentage,NotTestedPercentage  from #cte 

)P
UNPIVOT(Legend FOR  #CTE IN (Good,Fair,Poor,NotCategorised,NotTested))AS UNPVT;
```

I am not getting the required output

my result set need to be *like this :*

```
year    Legend  percent count
Dec-12  Good    13.89   35
Dec-12  Fair    0   0
Dec-12  Poor    0   0
Dec-12  NC  0   0
Dec-12  NoData  86.11   217
```

Suggest me the best way.

Comment: it's helpful to provide table definitions, and the results you're actually seeing.  The less we have to type in order to test the quicker you will get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify what version of SQL Server you are using but using UNPIVOT for your data might be more difficult since you want to unpivot the columns in sets.  It might be easier to use CROSS APPLY to get the result:

```
select dateperiod,
  Legend,
  [Percent],
  [Count]
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  select 'Good', Good, GoodPercentage union all
  select 'Fair', Fair, FairPercentage union all
  select 'Poor', Poor, PoorPercentage union all
  select 'NotCategorised', NotCategorised, NotCategorisedPercentage union all
  select 'NotTested', NotTested, NotTestedPercentage
) c (Legend, [Percent], [Count]);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d11b/1). If you are using a version of SQL Server that supports the VALUES clause then you could alter the above to the following:

```
select dateperiod,
  Legend,
  [Percent],
  [Count]
from yourtable t
cross apply
(
  values
    ('Good', Good, GoodPercentage),
    ('Fair', Fair, FairPercentage),
    ('Poor', Poor, PoorPercentage),
    ('NotCategorised', NotCategorised, NotCategorisedPercentage),
    ('NotTested', NotTested, NotTestedPercentage)
) c (Legend, [Percent], [Count]);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d11b/2). These give a result:

```
| DATEPERIOD |         LEGEND | PERCENT | COUNT |
|     Feb-13 |           Good |       4 |  6.25 |
|     Feb-13 |           Fair |       0 |     0 |
|     Feb-13 |           Poor |       0 |     0 |
|     Feb-13 | NotCategorised |       0 |     0 |
|     Feb-13 |      NotTested |      60 | 93.75 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `unpivot` twice.

```
Select 
    DatePeriod,
    Legend,
    amount,
    pc      
FROM 
(
select DatePeriod,
Good,Fair,Poor,NotCategorised,NotTested,GoodPercentage,
FairPercentage,poorPercentage,NotCategorisedPercentage,NotTestedPercentage  
from yourtable    
)P
UNPIVOT(Amount FOR  Legend IN (Good,Fair,Poor,NotCategorised,NotTested))AS UNPVT
unpivot(pc for var in (GoodPercentage, FairPercentage, PoorPercentage, NotCategorisedPercentage,NotTestedPercentage)) u2
where REPLACE(var,'Percentage','')=Legend
```

Or, if as it seems your data contains redundant information, do the percentage calculation

```
Select 
    DatePeriod,
    Legend,
    amount, 
    100.0*Amount/nullif(SUM(Amount) over (partition by dateperiod),0)

FROM 
(
select DatePeriod,
Good,Fair,Poor,NotCategorised,NotTested,GoodPercentage,
FairPercentage,poorPercentage,NotCategorisedPercentage,NotTestedPercentage  from @t

)P
UNPIVOT(Amount FOR  Legend IN (Good,Fair,Poor,NotCategorised,NotTested))AS UNPVT
```